# Static list and Garbage collector?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, garbage-collection

I've an application which may use a lot of data in each calculus.

I have a "class A" which contains a lot of attributes. I've around 10k objects of this class.

- So my idea was to load them only one time from the database and use them to search for example.

So I created a List :

```
public static List<ClassA>
```

in my application.

After some tests it's really faster than loading everytime my data from the database.

But I don't think this is a good way to do it ?
What about the garbage collector ? Can it becomes perturbed by this huge List of Data ?

- My second idea was to split my Class1 into different classes to have smaller requests from the DB. My code is more clean for sure. But really slow now.

The only big issue I see in the List method is the persistence of my Data : I have to modify the elements from my List (so search them in the list) and also persist them through EntityFramework instead of getting them from EF, modifying them then persisting them through EF.

For sure it seems to be "better" to avoid the list, but the performances are so bad if I don't use it.

- I used the profiler with the List, and it took a lot of time into the creation of the lists (each time I search something it returns a smaller list : for example take all objects where the attribute "Name" equals "blabla")

Comment: Is your concern primarily about the GC and it's nuances or the performance of CPU bound operations like your searches?

Comment: Both.
I thought maybe the GC could be perturbed with these huge lists of data but I want my application to be the fastest possible. THe real question was "what is the best pratice ? what a good developper would do ? :)

Answer (score 1):

> For sure it seems to be "better" to avoid the list, but the performances are so bad if I don't use it.

This is a very common tradeoff: you pay with memory for CPU cycles and network bandwidth. If you think it's a bad thing for the list to stay in memory forever (as a static list certainly would, until you explicitly clear it) you can create a "cache" object, store your list in it, and keep it around only for as long as it is needed. Once you're done with the list, get rid of your "cache" object, and your list would get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...Okay without a clear explaination of the entire application I am seeing some red flags here.

Firstly...My main concern here is that you say that you have done benchmarking and have shown that it is faster to load the entire database into your application than adhoc rehydrating each object each database call.

I would need to know how you are benchmarking to know if you are correct in your assumptions.

The reason is as follows.

On EF the main costs of queries is the latency to the database, the binding of the result set into objects and the compilation of the query.

On your static list, the main costs is iterating over an enormous dataset to find the correct items, threading bugs and more than likely an object in the LOH which will cause memory fragmentation.

For small numbers of objects, the cost of binding the objects to the datareader should be small, but the (one off) compilation cost is large. Assuming a well tuned database, the query should be hitting indices, which should make the I/O cost small on the database server.

Whilst a similar query against a large static list will be largely optimized (unless you write some kind of indexing code, like some kind of a relational data structure).

In the end without seeing how you are structuring your code, it is difficult to understand HOW you could be finding it faster to load an entire database into your application to be fast.

Could you show some code listings of how you are actually using EF, the classes involved, which version of .net framework you are running against etc...